# Problems with registering a COM+ dll in 64bit

Tags: visual-studio-2012, registry, 64-bit, windows-7-x64, com+

when we build a COM + application in windows7 64 bit  with "AnyCPU" or "X64" bit configuration we are not able register that dll by using below options

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regsvcs.exe" "...\ABC.dll"

The following installation error occurred:
1: Failed to load assembly 'ABC.dll'.
2: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///ABC.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

*Note:: i have checked properly all its dependency are built properly in 64 bit with 64 bit configuration.* 
*Note:: i am using "VS2012 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt" in Adminstrator mode to register*

This work fine if we build in windows 7 32bit.

any suggestions?

Comment: You are using the 32-bit version of regsvcs.exe.  The 64-bit version is located in Framework64.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant. It works

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this:

`"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regsvcs.exe" "...\ABC.dll"`

instead of this:

`"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regsvcs.exe" "...\ABC.dll"`

The difference is in the framework folder inside `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\`, `Framework64` instead of `Framework`.